# Replace dynamically content in a custom database table when a custom post is created

Tags: custom-post-types, database, customization

I use a third party plugin that saves events locations addresses as a custom *locations* post type in a separate table - *wp_em_locations*.

Because events are created by multiple authors, they write sometimes differently the name of the same town, using different languages. **How can I filter dynamically that names when the post is created and replace them with a default one?**

For example, the Kiev town name can be written as Kiev, Киев, Kyiv and Київ, but I want to save only one of them. Town names are saved in the *location_town* column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that creates one common question for all **SW engineers**. How you can do this “guide the user to select” and also “provide the capability” so the user can add their own data. Well, there is **not an easy way to do it**. You can try different technics like live searching, recommendation for the input and all short of miracles but the end result will always be dictated by the user.

If you restricted to the user role if not high enough will be only allowed to add preexisting “towns” this can solve few miswrites but will have a significant drawback which is the review process or the request to add this user-defined inputs.

I would suggest allowing the users input after the couldn’t find the “town from the list”. 
The “darker” path will be creating mapper for all towns and cross-checking to the user input.

Answer (score 1):

I would do that by adding a new column named for example `nodes`, so you will have table like

```
ID|  name  |      nodes 
-----------------------------
1 | "Kiev" | "Киев Kyiv Київ"
```

and your suggestion plugin will search in both colums and when user will select it, then ID 1 will be retrieved